# Firebase setting value from another key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that sets two values to zero. Is there a way to set the value of "lastDaily" to whatever the value of "click" is before setting click to 0?

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule("01 0 * * *")
    .timeZone("Europe/London")
    .onRun((context) => {
      dbCon.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          child.ref.update({
            lastDaily: 0,
            click: 0,
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule("01 0 * * *")
    .timeZone("Europe/London")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
        
        const snapshot = await dbCon.get();
        
        const promises = [];
        
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            const oldClickValue = child.val().lastDaily;
            promises.push(child.ref.update({
                lastDaily: oldClickValue,
                click: 0,
            }));
        })
        
        return Promise.all(promises);
        
    });
```

Note that we use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to return a Promise when [all the asynchronous work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). For the same reason note that we use the `get()` method, which returns a Promise.

---

Another solution, instead of `Promise.all()`, would be to use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#update) method as shown in this [documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).